# c# portable class library: find item in list by property

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, portable-class-library

I am developing a Windows Phone 8 application where I use portable class libraries.
There seems to be no linq-support for these kind of projects.

Is there a good/recommended way to search for an item in a list based on a property value?

If i get it right, I can't use something like: `list.Find(i => i.ID == someValue);`

Edit: I'm currently using `foreach` but would like to know if there is another solution.

The PCL settings are:
.NET 4.5, Silverlight 4, Windows Phone 7.5 and Windows Store

Comment: `foreach`? it's all linq does under the hod anyway

Comment: I'm currently using it (foreach), was just curious if there exists another solution. Should have added that to the question...

Comment: How comes there's no LINQ support for PCL? Do you have some reference to MSDN in this regard?

Comment: Re lack of LINQ support in PCL: this link says List<T>.Find method is supported in PCL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx

Comment: LINQ is available in PCL's. I'm using it right now.

Comment: In the future, when you ask a question about PCL, please specify which frameworks you limited your PCL project to. It's very much relevant.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen: You're right. My settings are:
.NET 4.5,
Silverlight 4,
Windows Phone 7.5 and
Windows Store

Comment: You can edit your question and add it there as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you don't need Xbox then you can use LINQ in PCL.
[Blog post](http://kishore1021.wordpress.com/2012/08/06/what-is-portable-class-library-project-in-visual-studio-2012-net-4-5/) explaining restrictions when using PCL.

LINQ code:

```
list.FirstOrDefault(i=>i.ID==someValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use list.FirstOrDefault(i=>i.ID==someValue);

Comment: The System.Linq Namespace is definitively available in a PCL. I just added it to one of mine!

Answer (score -1):

Good old binary search should do the trick, if the list is sorted by the search property. Then you'll have O(log(n)) computational complexity with it, instead of O(n) with `foreach`, though overhead for sorting and certain list sizes could make all this tricks negligible.